# Regular Expression to match specific string followed by number?

Tags: regex

What regular expression can I use to find this?

```
&v=15151651616
```

Where `&v=` is a static string and the number part may vary.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`"^&v=[0-9]+$"` if you want at least 1 number or `"^&v=[0-9]*$"` if no number must match too.

If you want it to match inside another sequence just remove the `^` and `$`, which means the sequence beginning by `(^)` and sequence ending with `($)`

Answer (score 28):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
&v=\d+
```

This matches `&v=` and then one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other solutions but those were not working for me but the following worked.

```
NAME(column):
    dbbdb
    abcdef=1244
    abc =123sfdafs
    abc= 1223 adsfa
    abc = 1323def
    abcasdafs =adfd 1323def
```

To find 'bc' followed by a number, Code:
. -> match any character
? -> optional (show even if there are no characters)
+ -> in addition to the search keyword

```
where regexp_like (NAME, 'bc.?+[0-9]');
Output:
abcdef=1244
abc =123sfdafs
abc= 1223 adsfa
abc = 1323def
abcasdafs =adfd 1323def
```

To find 'bc' followed by '=' and a number, no matter the spaces, Code:

```
where regexp_like (NAME, 'bc ?+[=] ?+[0-9]');
Output:
abc =123sfdafs
abc= 1223 adsfa
abc = 1323def
```