# How to regex for alphanumeric pattern with specific string

Tags: regex

### Needle in haystack: Specific string followed by exact set of numbers

How can I search for `ABC????` where ABC should be exactly that, but the ???? must be exactly *four numbers*, ideally followed by whitespace.

*Illustrative examples:*

- `LHRJFKABC1234 233` <-- Has needle
- `EABC123 LHRJFK` <-- Does not have needle as only 3 numbers following ABC

Something tells me I need to search for string + something like `(\d{4})` for the 4 numbers. But not sure quite how to puzzle it all together.

What I've found so far:

- [Regular expression to match standard 10 digit phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number)
- [Regular Expression to match specific string followed by number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411584/regular-expression-to-match-specific-string-followed-by-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things like this I find an online checker like [Rubular](https://rubular.com/) very handy.

Unless I'm misunderstanding, the regex `ABC\d{4}\s` should work for you. Do you need groupings (i.e. to match the 4-digit part)?

Try it out on Rubular [here](https://rubular.com/r/r4dqfXezBS9Y34)